# VScode Java/Maven environment problem different computers

Tags: java, xml, maven, compilation

Im using jdk1.8.0_191, jre1.8.0_191 and apache-maven-3.6.2.

I have a pretty big open liberty / maven project that uses the javax.xml.bind maven library :

```
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>
```

The problem occurs on one pc, not on the other. The javax.xml.bind.*; is rendered different on the different computers causing compilation errors , for example im trying to use the class 
`JAXBContext.newInstance(Class.class)` 
which works fine on one computer since the method that i can peek definition is as follows:

```
public static JAXBContext newInstance( Class... classesToBeBound )
        throws JAXBException {

        return newInstance(classesToBeBound,Collections.<String,Object>emptyMap());
    }
```

But on my ohter pc the class method is rendered like :

```
public static javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext newInstance(java.lang.String pPath) throws javax.xml.bind.JAXBException {
   return null; 
 }
```

This causes compilation error like

```
The method newInstance(String) in the type JAXBContext is not applicable for the arguments (Class<FormObject>)
```

Also the JAXContext.class file in the none working one has the comment above

```
 // Failed to get sources. Instead, stub sources have been generated by the disassembler.
 // Implementation of methods is unavailable.
```

, and the one that is working has a bunch of documentation.

There's more bugs from the javax.xml.bind.*; lib like that javax.xml.bind.Marshaller for instance. Ive tried to do mvn clean install but nothing seems to fix this issue!

Comment: Is the given runtime really `jre1.9-0_191`?

Comment: no sorry its jre1.8.0_191, i changed it

Comment: Ok so not a JDK9+ problem. have configured all your plugin with version also all dependencies have you check on both pc what `mvn dependency:tree` is showing? Is the other pc correctly configured to be able to access central repository to download dependencies? Is the settings.xml file the same as on the other machine?

Comment: mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean install, solved the problem